# Set up Seq logging dashboard with ExecutionTime attribute

Tags: seq-logging, datalust-seq

I want to set up a Seq logging dashboard based on ExecutionTime attribute. That attribute logs the time taken by a particular event in my webapp.
What query should I use to list the timing information for all the events? I want to filter by a particular event and would also like to highlight events that take more than 2 ms.

Some sample vents as follows:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can chart every `ExecutionTime` on the events page with a query like:

```
select @Timestamp, ExecutionTimefrom stream where Has(ExecutionTime) limit 1000
```

You can't put this on a dashboard, because dashboards are always grouped by time. To put it on a dashboard you have to aggregate the `ExecutionTime` values using a function like `max`, `mean` or `percentile`.

For events that take more than two milliseconds you can create a separate chart or setup an event for that condition.